# Existing power supply supported by new motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

Essentially, I'd like to confirm that my Silencer 750W Crossfire power supply is supported by the Asus Z97-A.

The motherboard states `24-pin EATX Power connector`:
http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813132118

The power supply states `20+4Pin`:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817341011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better question would be does the power supply support ALL the power pin requirements. Not only the 24 pin (and yes it does with the 20+4) but the 8-pin EATX 12V Power connector as well(see your mobo specs).

In fact, your selected power supply does have that additional 8 pin connector. Be sure to plug it in or your new build will most likely not start up.

My mobo, ASUS Crosshair V Formula-Z has a 24 pin, 8 pin and 4 pin power connector. In my case, I must have the 8 pin hooked up. The 4 pin would be to support additional power for OC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.  The 20+4 connector on your PSU means it can support motherboards that require a 20 pin or a 24 pin PSU.  The last 4 pins are removable to support older motherboards.